How does a language end up with ergative-absolutive alignment on nouns, but nominative-accusative in verb concord?
In Two Types of Ergative Agreement: Implications for Case (Coon, 2015), the author explains that there are broadly two different ways a language can be "ergative". One is that it can be ergative in its case-marking; that is, the nouns in the P/S roles can receive a different case than nouns in the A role. The second is it can be ergative in its verb concord: there can be one set of markers for arguments in the P/S roles, and a different set of markers for the arguments in the A role. She uses this table to show that these two "types of ergative agreement" are independent of each other, and don't actually have to co-occur:

A similar table can be found in Ergative Agreement Systems (Woolford, 1999):

Coon spends much of the article arguing for why the bottom row (what she's labelling as ⑤ and ⑥) is necessary, and the theoretical reason why ② wouldn't exist. But what I'm more confused about, and what she does not address at all as far as I can tell, is why ③ does exist.
③, as far as I understand, implies that the A and S receive the same marking on the verb and P having a different verb marker, while on nouns P/S are the same and A is different. My understanding is that this is what Sumerian does; the noun cases are always Erg/Abs, but in the maru (non-past?), the verb marks transitive agents the same as intransitive subjects - which is a Nom/Acc pattern, not Erg/Abs.
...how? How do you end up with a systematic mismatch between the case marking and the verb marking like this?
I don't understand how that would happen as opposed to just having a set of verb markers that agree with the absolutive, and another set that agrees with ergative, i.e. P/S vs. A on both nouns and verbs. This is what Coon is labelling as ④. The process for how that would come about makes more sense to me; intuitively I guess you would start with an intransitive verb and then evolve subject marking. An oblique agent (ablative, instrumental, genitive, etc.) could be later be introduced; this later gets reanalyzed as ergative, but the existing verb agreement is already with the argument that existed before the ergative was added, i.e. with what is now the absolutive. This is what IINM happened with Hindi with the added wrinkle that because it started from an IE Nom/Acc starting point, there had to be a passivization step to get rid of the accusative to arrive at the "intransitive verb with subject marking" step.

Let's analyse the Nepali example given by Coon:

मैले यस पसलमा पत्रिका किने।
mai-lē yas pasal-mā patrikā kin-ē.
1SG.ERG DEM store-LOC newspaper.ABS buy-PAST-1SG
'I bought the newspaper in this store.'

The pronoun 'I' म ma takes on its ergative form, with the marker -ले -lē. The absolutive on पत्रिका patrikā 'newspaper' is unmarked, and the verb किन्नु kinnu 'to buy' is conjugated in the simple past, triggering ergative-absolutive alignment. But it is in the first person simple past, किने/किनें kinē/kinē̃, rather than the third person.
Compare this to Hindi:

मैंने इस दुकान से अख़बार ख़रीदा।
mãi-ne is dukān se axbār xarīd-ā.
1SG.ERG DEM store LOC newspaper.ABS buy-PERF-MASC

The verb ख़रीदना xarīdnā 'to buy' is conjugated into its perfective form, where there is no agreement in person. The perfective here does not even distinguish 1st, 2nd and 3rd persons (although it does for plurality and certain levels of honorificity in the 2nd person).
There is however agreement with the grammatical gender of the absolutive patient, as अख़बार axbār 'newspaper' is masculine. Using a patient with feminine gender (किताब kitāb 'book') and an agent with masculine gender, we see feminine marking on the verb.

राम ने किताब ख़रीदी।
Rām ne kitāb xarīd-ī.
Rama ERG book buy-PERF-FEM
'Rama bought the book.'

This dissociation of nominal object and verb case marking seems to be traceable to the collapse of the case system in Middle Indo-Aryan. Patel-Grosz (2021) cites a phonological development where the nominative and instrumental cases became partially syncretised, and this was strengthened in Old Hindi, but weakened in e.g. Old Bengali, which would then lose ergative marking altogether.
Why Hindi/Urdu retained agreement with the object in the transitive verb whereas Nepali went onto agent-targeting agreement may have to do with different information structures, the so-called 'focus hypothesis'. This is even an optional feature of Nepali in non-perfective sentences. Could this be related to Nepali's high level of contact with Sino-Tibetan languages (many of which are also [somewhat!] ergative)? It is a tantalising proposal, but I think the characterisation of the semantics of the Nepali ergative are not finalised yet.

The Hindi example looks superficially quite similar to Inuit constructions where the ergative alignment is historically due to the now-transitive verb being in origin a possessed participle, the possessive being indicated by the now-ergative case (e.g., ‘I bought the newspaper’ < ‘the newspaper [is] my bought [thing]’).
